# Resolve one hostname to another, using hosts file

Tags: dns, hosts

I know how to resolve a hostname to an IP address using my hosts file eg

```
1.2.3.4 example.com
```

but is it possible to resolve a hostname to another

```
example.com example1.com
```

with a hosts file? Reason being, Im testing a new site, hosting uses Virtual hosts, so there are multiple domains on the IP address. ServerAlias in Apache is not an option either.

Any help appreciated!

Thanks
Stephen

Comment: Why can't you simply hostfile domain 2 to the same IP address? You would end on the same webserver for testing.

Comment: @Tejs - Perhaps because the first hostname is actually derived from DNS?

Comment: @stephen - Have you tried it?

Answer (score 11):

No.

You can add multiple hostnames to the hostfile, for example:
 1.2.3.4 hostname1 hostname2

But every time you look up a name or address, youll just get the whole line back. Or was that what you wanted?

Answer (score 5):

You can't resolve one domain to another, but you can have multiple hostnames for one IP like this:

```
1.2.3.4 example.com
1.2.3.4 example1.com
1.2.3.4 example.net
1.2.3.4 example.net
```

Comment: or `1.2.3.4 example.com example1.com example.net`